# Calculator positive and negative sign

Tags: c#, .net, calculator

I'm learning to create a calculator program. But I'm kinda frustated on how to make the numbers positive or negative. Just like we see in a normal calculator. 
I'm not really sure how can I make a positive number turn to a negative or make the negative sign positive again by using a button to a textbox.

If I press a button, the number goes directly to the textbox.

private void No1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {
        NumBox1.Text = NumBox1.Text + "1";
    }
```

How can I make the number inside NumBox1.text to a negative or positive sign?
Please help!!!!

I'm using c# language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your follow up comments to both of the posted answers, you're unsure of the numeric value that's entered in the box at the time and need to know how to negate the value without parsing, multiplying by negative one, `ToString`ing the value and putting it back in the box.

If that's the case, (and you don't want to follow the above procedure as you might lose trailing or leading zeroes or just don't want to change the user's input)

```
private void NegateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(NumBox1.Text.StartsWith("-"))
    {
        //It's negative now, so strip the `-` sign to make it positive
        NumBox1.Text = NumBox1.Text.Substring(1);
    }
    else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NumBox1.Text) && decimal.Parse(NumBox1.Text) != 0)
    {
        //It's positive now, so prefix the value with the `-` sign to make it negative
        NumBox1.Text = "-" + NumBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a substring? I know c# but not that yet good. =) I copied the code and get it correct.

Comment: @MAG a substring is a part of a string, for example, if I have the string `ABCD` then `AB` is a substring of it, as it can be found in the original string. The substring method takes characters from the string starting at a given offset into the string (one character in the code above) and returns a certain number of characters from that position. The particular overload of the method used in the code above returns all characters at and after the supplied index. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: so the first statement here states that, "if the numbox1.text starts with a (-), then the result will be like start from the first character of the string, right?" then the second statement here states that, "if not string is null or empty inside the numbox1.text and (I'm not sure how to explain the next part especially the parse identifier) is not equals to zero then numbox1.text will all (-) plus the current value inside the numbox1.text" was that right? :)

Comment: In C# indexes start at 0, so `Substring(1)` is everything at or after the second character (at index 1 - offset one character from the first). Apart from that, right.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, assuming that you're using a C-like programming language:

```
int x = 10;  // positive
x = -1 * x   // negative

int y = -10; // negative
y = -1 * y   // positive
```

So you see, you just have to multiply the number times `-1` to flip the sign. Alternatively, you can use the `-` operator for the same effect:

```
int x = 10;  // positive
x = -x       // negative

int y = -10; // negative
y = -y       // positive
```

Comment: Hahaha. I didn't think of that. xD
so the if statement would go like this?

if (num >1) // positive
{
num = -1 * num; // negative
}
if (num < 1) // negative
{
num = -1 * num; // positive
}

Comment: @MAG there isn't even need for an `if` statement. Simply do this: `num = -num;` or this: `num = -1 * num;`, it's the same

Comment: I'm using a c# language and a button. oh yeah, I forgot I don't have an variable for the number buttons since it goes directly to the textbox. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

First off, it may help to include more information about what you're trying to do, such as the language you are using, whether the issue is creating a button or doing the math, etc.

However, if you are trying simply trying reverse the sign of a number, try multiplying the number by -1.  That will flip the sign.

Examples:

```
3.5521 * -1 = -3.5521
-104.2 * -1 = +104.2
0.0000 * -1 = 0
```

Comment: I'm using a c# language and a button. oh yeah, I forgot I don't have an variable for the number buttons since it goes directly to the textbox. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to insert into your button:

```
TextBox2.Text = "-" & TextBox2.Text
    Button2.Enabled = False

//or even as simply as this: 
display.Text = "-" + display.Text;
```